# Compare Strings in the Python Input List

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have code like this :

```
n = list(input().split()) #Input score in alphabet
for i in n :
    if i == "E" : 
        print("You Have Bad Score") #if you have an E score, then you cant pass
    elif len(n) < 7 :
        print("Your score does not qualify") #must enter at least 8 values
    else :
        print("You pass")

# Output
A B C C D D D E = Your have bad score
A B B A A B B C = You Pass
A B B B A = Your score doesn't qualify
```

But the problem in my code is when i input A B C C D D D E the output is "You Pass" not "You have bad score". Can you help me ?

Comment: Can you fix the provided code first. I don't see an `x` defined in your code which you are using in your if condition.

Comment: Oh, wrong write, i will edit it

Comment: @TitoYudha- you can read my post and see if that help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your codes has some mistypes or errors: 1. the `x` should be `n`. Secondly, try to use more descriptive variable name to help you.
[Notes - you still have to fix/work out the multiple print statements issues...]

Try this it should help you find out.

```py
scores = list(input().split()) #Input score in alphabet
print(scores)    # you can comment this out 

for s in scores:

    if any(s == 'E' for s in scores): 
        print("You Have Bad Score")   # earlier bail-out when `E` scores.
        break
    elif len(scores) < 7 :
        print("Your score does not qualify") #must enter at least 8 values
    else :
        print("You pass")

# Output
# A B C C D D D E = Your have bad score
# A B B A A B B C = You Pass

#A B B B A = Your score doesn't qualify

# Sample Run - with # first list of given scores:
A B C C D D D E
['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'E']

You Have Bad Score           # changed as the new Req. asked!
```

Comment: thank you for correction my code, i edited it

Comment: Glad that it works.  Let's us know if you have any further questions.  Would you accept this post then?

Comment: OK. If you want to get the `bad score` - then you can do this: if any(s == 'E' for s in scores):
    print('You got bad scores!')        # where you put it, depends on your design...

Comment: Can you help me, how to get only "You have bad score ?" without "you pass" ?

Comment: Ugh okay, i will try it, thank you i will accept this post soon

Comment: Change the `You have bad score` as you requested now (new req.!) and `break` the loop - no more print `You passed`...    Please don't keep changing req.

Answer (score 1):

Here, you are printing all the options.

Means, for example the imput is A B C D E, then there will be 4 statements that you pass and one says you have bad score. If you just want one output as you pass, remove the print statement in the loop. Use a boolean flag like below.

Also, no need to check if length of scores is less than 8 in the loop. Take it outside and don't continue further. I don't see it as useful inside loop according to the current context.

```
isFail = false
if len(scores) < 8:
    print("you didn't qualify")
for i in scores:
    if i == "E":
        isFail= true
if isFail :
     print("you have bad score")
else:
    print("you pass")
```

Comment: Glad to hear. Accept an answer and mark the question as closed if you don't need anymore answers.